# Capybara unable to click form button in modal and different capybara drivers see different things

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, capybara, capybara-webkit

Ok, so my problem is Capybara cannot click the submit button of a form (generated with simple forms) that resides in a modal(Bootstrap v2.3). Please note that the following code is very messy learners code. I am attempting to get it tested up so that I can refactor the hell out of it.

Modal code:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="updateModal">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <div class="modal-header"
      <h3>Update your score</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= simple_form_for @update do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
          <%= f.input :newread , :label => "Amount Read", :placeholder => 'pages/screens/minutes #' , :input_html => { :maxlength => 5 } %>
          <%= f.input :medium, :label=> "Medium Read", :collection => ["book", "manga", "game", "fgame", "net", "lyric", "subs", "news", "sent", "nico" ], :prompt => "Select medium read" %>
          <% lang_list = Update::user_langs(current_user,ApplicationHelper::curr_round) %>
          <%= f.input :lang, :label => "Language", :collection => lang_list, :prompt => "Select your language" %>
          <%= f.input :repeat, :label => "Repeat number", :collection =>0..50 , :priority => '0' %>
          <%= f.input :dr, :inline_label => 'Double Rowed?', :hint => 'Only to be used with Japanese books', :label => false %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= submit_tag 'Cancel', :class => "btn btn-danger", 'data-dismiss' => "modal" %>
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Update' , :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
      </div>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

Round Controller index function:

```
  def index
    @entrants = Round.includes(:user).where(:round_id => "#{ApplicationHelper::curr_round}")
    if @entrants == nil
      redirect_to root_url, :flash => { :error => "There are currently no users registered for this round." }
    end

    list = Round.where(:round_id => ApplicationHelper::curr_round).select(:tier).uniq
    lang_list = Update.where(:round_id => ApplicationHelper::curr_round).select(:lang).uniq
    @tier = list.map(&:tier)
    @tier = @tier.sort{ |a,b|  Tier::TIER_VALUES[a.to_sym] <=> Tier::TIER_VALUES[b.to_sym]}
    @lang = lang_list.map(&:lang)
    if signed_in?
      @update = current_user.updates.build
    end
  end
```

Update_page_spec:

```
describe "Update Pages" do

before do
  sign_in #omniauth fake signin
end

subject { page }

  describe "a registered user submitting an update", :js => true do
    before do
      user = User.find_by_uid(123545)
      user_round = user.rounds.create!(round_id: ApplicationHelper::curr_round, lang1: 'jp',
                                                      lang2: 'en', lang3:'zh', tier: 'Bronze', book:  10, manga: 10,
                                                      fgame: 10, game: 10, net: 10, news: 10, lyric: 10,
                                                      subs: 10, nico: 10, sent:10, pcount: 1010)
      visit round_path(ApplicationHelper.curr_round)
    end

    it "should update successfully" do
      click_link("Update")
      fill_in('update[newread]', :with => '10')
      select "book", :from => "Medium Read"
      select "Japanese", :from => "Language"
      click_button "Submit Update"
      save_and_open_page
      page.should have_selector('alert-success', :text => "Update successfully submitted")
    end
  end
end
```

So I do this and when I check what `save_and_open_page` sees and its the page with no changes at all. No evidence of the button having been pressed what so ever. So I figure that the modal being js generated might be a problem so I add `, :js => true` to the `describe` line, install the webkit driver and add `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` to my `spec_helper.rb` file and run it again.

This time I am greeted to the "Signed in" flash from the top before block on the home page instead of being on the ranking page.

So I figure maybe this might turn out better with the selenium driver so I install that and try it again but this time my app complains about there being no one registered for that round. The only way for this to happen is if `@entrants` is nil and I have checked with pry that this is definitely not the case at least as far as the database is concerned.

Any help you guys can give will be **GREATLY** appreciated. I have no idea how to get this thing to press my button.

Comment: To be clear, the attempt without the `:js => true` gets the closest but it just can't seem to press the button for some unknown reason.

Comment: Yes, if clicking "Update" runs Javascript you need a Javascript driver, so we won't worry about the non-Javascript result. I don't understand why different Javascript drivers gave different results. Please be clear about the error you're seeing with the one that you're using now, and the step that you get it at.

Comment: @SomberClock Please, prepare an example application (a just a suite of HTML/JS/Ruby code etc.) that would allow to reproduce this issue. It will greatly help others in investigating and fixing it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Actual code and tests are up and here is the repo for the application. https://github.com/Hobogrammer/Tadoku-App/tree/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation:

- Clean up the code as much as you can. That will help clarify what is happening, and what may be responsible for the unexpected behavior.
- Don't rely on `save_and_open_page` to accurately show you what the driver is seeing exactly
- You definitely need js for the [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)
- Get selenium working with Firefox so you can see on your screen if the modal is opening properly or not.
- You may need the database_cleaner gem to properly access your db with the users you are creating.
- you can also try the poltergeist/phantom gems for a js compatible driver. That has [screenshot capabilities](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging)

Those pieces should show you what's happening with the modal.

Comment: is this answer for that question?